# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space to upload 8 MB size file

Tags: grails, groovy, out-of-memory, apache-poi

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and trying to upload a .xlsx file using the 'apache poi' plugin but I am getting JAVA Heap size exception when the file size is around 8 MB.

My Controller has the following action and methods:-

```
def uploadForm() {       
       String fileName = "D:\\File.xlsx"
       Map excelSheetMap = process(fileName)
}

Map process(String fileName) {
    ExcelBuilder excelBuilder = new ExcelBuilder(fileName)  
    //Getting JAVA Heap Size exception here when I am trying to create an object 
    //of ExcelBuilder with the file      
}
```

ExcelBuilder.groovy class file looks something like this

```
class ExcelBuilder {
   Workbook workbook
   ExcelBuilder(String fileName) {      
      new File(fileName).withInputStream { is ->
         workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried using the grails-excel-import plugin as well but I am getting the same exception.

Can someone please suggest how to import big size excel files in grails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the app memory? E.g. `run    : [maxMemory: 1280, minMemory: 128, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve: true, jvmArgs: jvmArgs]` in your BuildConfig?

Comment: yes, I have already tried this but getting same.

Comment: And if you create a small project (grails-less), potentially groovy script, to test just the loading od the file, would it work?

Comment: Have you tried using `jmc` or `jvisualvm` to see where the memory is going?

Comment: If you run your jvm with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, you can analyze the heap dump after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Poi does have a high memory footprint. Please see:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

You can try SXSSF. SXSSF is an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF to be used when very large spreadsheets have to be produced, and heap space is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this 'XSSF API' is that when I have created the root object(workbook) for the excel sheet, heap space is full while generating the object and there is lack of heap space for building the workbook object. So it is less possible to process the sheet after increasing the heap size because excel sheet can be much larger.

```
new File(fileName).withInputStream { is ->
         workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)
         //Getting JAVA Heap Size exception here when I am trying to create  an object 
      }
```

So after some R&D I have found one more API to process large excel sheet i.e. "XSSF and SAX (Event API)". But for this you can get at the underlying XML data, and process it yourself.

You can find the complete documentation here- 
https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an `InputStream` when you have a `File`? The docs are [quite clear on that needing more memory](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!